# Why can't I get the X axis to be labeled?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

For some reason I can't manage to get the x axis labels to show. Context: this is supposed to be continuous work over the time of a week.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# FIGURE #####

oneseventh <- 1/7
work <-c(oneseventh)
work <- rep(work,each=7)
days_num <-c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7")
days_vec <- c(1:7)
npro_data <- data.frame(work)

npro_plot <- ggplot(npro_data, aes(x=1:7, y=work,))
npro_plot + labs(x = "Days of the Week", 
                y ="Amount of Work per day (%)", 
                title = "Non-Procrastinator",
                tag = "A",
                caption = "(based on data from ...)") + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim =c(1, 7), ylim = c(0,100)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=days_num,breaks=days_num) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()

#
```

See the plot I get with this code:
[image: See the plot I get with this code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you used `x = 1:7` in your `ggplot(aes)`, you have to specify a `scale_x_continuous` (since `1:7` would be a continuous variable, not categorical or discrete). Also, you don't need to use the `labels` argument in `scale_x_continuous`, setting the `breaks` is already enough.

If it's possible, I would recommend to include all variables that are involved in the `ggplot` in the input dataframe (i.e. your `npro_data`). It'd be much easier to handle and avoid ambiguity.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(npro_data, aes(x=1:7, y=work,)) + 
  labs(x = "Days of the Week", 
       y ="Amount of Work per day (%)", 
       title = "Non-Procrastinator",
       tag = "A",
       caption = "(based on data from ...)") + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim =c(1, 7), ylim = c(0,100)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = days_vec) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image: geom_point]

However, since in your question you mentioned that you would like the x-axis to be weekdays, then it'd probably be better to include `days_num` in your `npro_data`, and map that to the x aesthetics in `ggplot`. You'll need to use `scale_x_discrete` to change the labelling and breaks if that is the case.